# Android - Hide notification bar but keep navigation one

Tags: android, reflection, root, android-notifications, statusbar

I'm creating a kind of `Kiosk application` for Android but I must disable the notification bar to avoid the customers to access `Wifi`, `Bluetooth` or `GPS` quick access.

So far I've rooted the device and disabled the `com.android.systemui` package to achieve that. The main issue is, as I got only virtual buttons to navigate, I can't go back or go to home screen. Basically I'm stucked on the application and I can't do anything.

I've used that code to disable the `SystemUI` package:

```
pm disable com.android.systemui
```

Then I've tried to disable the `notification bar` using the `Java reflection API`. So far, I've made that code but it doesn't work. Basically, it just throws an `exception` saying my application doesn't have the required permission `android.permission.STATUS_BAR` whereas it's written in my `Manifest`.

```
try
{
    Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
    Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("disable", int.class);
    collapse.setAccessible(true);
    collapse.invoke(service, 0x00000001);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Did I make something wrong on that part of code ?**

An alternative would be to create a `System overlay` to create my own `navigation bar`, but I haven't find a proper way to trigger a `KeyEvent` to the whole system as if it was the "real" buttons. But honnestly, I don't think this would be the best and cleanest solution to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In styles.xml:

```
<resources>
   <style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Refer to your custom style in your mainfest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen"/>
```

or TODO it programatically just do

```
// Remove System bar (and retain title bar)
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in code it looks like

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Remove System bar (and retain title bar)
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // Set your layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: The notification bar is still accessible with that code. If the user swipe from the top to the bottom, the notification bar appears and is accessible.

Comment: Let me Check a solution at my side for that

Comment: this is possible in rooted device i dont have a rooted device at the moment.